# Raw-image с камеры

Tags: android, камера, java

Собственно вопрос: удавалось ли кому-то (как-то) вытащить из камеры на Андроид-девайсе картинку в RAW? Много гуглил, но как-то бесполезно. Пишут, что нельзя, хотя коллбеки для этого есть (которые null возвращают). Но быть может есть способ?

Comment: JPEG-формирует "драйвер" фотика. Который зачастую прилизывает ту какашку, которую отдаёт недорогая микрокамера телефона, к чему-то более-менее удобоваримому. Если драйвер не знает о РАВе, то и будет отдавать нуль.

Аппаратно-то они почти все RAW отдают, но толку с этого...

Comment: Любая фотокамера снимает в RAW, но не любая его отдает. RAW - это данные сенсора фотокамеры с минимальной обработкой. JPEG же часть данных теряет. RAW нужен для того, чтобы можно было обработать картинку по своему с данных как они есть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для тех кому интересно. Мысли такие.

Вообщем, ситуация такая: самой ОС отдача RAW-картинки предусмотрена в коллбеке, а вот вендоры такую возможность для камер смартфонов не предусматривают. Это сделано специально, так как:

1. смартфон - не фотоаппарат и нефиг
2. Raw кушает очень много памяти, а ее обычно и так немного

Есть еще превью-коллбек, в котором тоже крутится якобы raw и можно попробовать вытащить его оттуда, но чую там также не все так просто. Да и задача была делать фотку в raw.